# How to not return nonType in this definition?

Tags: python, recursion, return

How can I return the value of `total_square` only when `quasi_gen==0?` If I put another return statement to the case where `quasi_gen>0`, then it always returns `zero`.

```
def count_boxes(quasi_gen, initial_list):

    total_square=0
    new_list=[]
    new_list=[box * 2 for box in initial_list]
    concatenate_list=initial_list+new_list

    if quasi_gen>0:
        quasi_gen-=1
        count_boxes(quasi_gen, concatenate_list)
    elif quasi_gen==0:
        total_square=(sum(elem for elem in concatenate_list))
        return(total_square)

count_boxes(4, [2,2])
```

Comment: write your expected output

Comment: Where were you putting the `return`? Review how recursion works and think about what should be returned when `quasi_gen > 0`.

Comment: expected to return 972. If I change return to print, that is what it prints, but its a nontype. I don't want to return anything in the case: quasi_gen > 0. I just keep decreasing 'gen' till it gets to zero. And when it does I return the value of interest which is total_square.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you're trying to do but first of all you should safe guard against quasi_gen < 0

you also don't need to do all those useless resets, in short, try this:

```
def count_boxes(quasi_gen, initial_list):

concatenate_list=initial_list + [box * 2 for box in initial_list]

if quasi_gen < 0:
    return 0  # ?
if quasi_gen > 0:
    return count_boxes(quasi_gen - 1, concatenate_list)
return(sum(elem for elem in concatenate_list))
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to call `return` on the first `if/else` branch:

```
if quasi_gen>0:
    quasi_gen-=1
    return count_boxes(quasi_gen, concatenate_list)
```

Like this you will be returning the result of the recursive call.